# Android voice recorder that will allow me to save to dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox, voice-recording

I really like the native voice recorder that comes with the Galaxy Note 4.

It's lightweight, simple, does what I want.

However, I can't tell it to save to my dropbox. I can either save on device, or save to SD card.

Is there a voice recorder that will allow me to specify to save to drop box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Using my site's [app search by permission](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/search) to check for voice recorders having the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission required to figure your Dropbox account (but could also be used for other cloud services), I could find 7 possible candidates I've checked a little closer:</sup>

According to its description, **[Voice Recorder - Dictaphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smsrobot.voicerecorder)** fits your needs:

> - Manual and Automatic Dropbox Synchronization
> - Manual and Automatic Google Drive Synchronization

It seems to be a feature-rich dictaphone app, and as such might not be "lightweight and simple" (6MB+ `.apk` size). So, checking further:

---

**[Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.impressive4.voicerecorderr)**, having just ~2MB `.apk` size, also offers Dropbox support:

> Voice Recorder is free, full-featured, superbly developed and easy to use voice recorder app for android, our app very helpful utility that allows the user to record and save the important lectures, conversations, voice recordings, song. You can Use it for record voice notes, talks, music and songs in high quality.

Its listed features hold a.o.

> - User friendly interface
> - Share recording via drop box or Google Drive

So this seems to perfectly fit your needs.

[image: Record] [image: Play] [image: Share 2 Dropbox]
<sup>Record, Play, Save to Dropbox (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.impressive4.voicerecorderr); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Be welcome to investigate the other candidates using above mentioned search.

Comment: Huh, I did not know you could search that way. Thanks.

Comment: Not before I setup that site, no :) Details on our Android sister-site: [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20619/16575) – There's also an app for that, Galen did a good job on it :) Trick is to know how things are tied together (like here: to store/retrieve with Dropbox, you need access to that account or at least to know there is one. Hence, checking for apps in the corresponding category having the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission pretty much did it. (and don't forget to upvote/accept this answer ;)

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help, I used Voice Recorder- Dictaphone. Costs $1.49 for full functionality - worth it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a IFTTT Recipe for this. You can pre-select a folder that whenever a file is a New file in that folder, It uploads it to dropbox.

[here is the recipe](https://ifttt.com/channels/dropbox/triggers/107-new-file-in-your-folder)

[Drobox automator](http://wappwolf.com/dropboxautomator) also lets you do the same thing by adding a pre-select folder to sync with Dropbox. So you can add the folder where your voice recordings are getting stored be it on the SD Card or Internal Memory

Answer (score 1):

Try VoiceDrop for Android. Specifically designed for uploading audio voice notes, memos and meetings to DropBox.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inniwinni.voicedrop&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the native app, at least you can on the GS5...
Just tap the hamburger icon (the three bars) [image: Hamburger icon screenshot]!
to get to your list of recordings and tap and hold the recording you want to upload.
You will get the "Share" icon, (the three interconnected dots,)
[image: Share icon]!
The trash icon and the more options ellipses.
Tap the Share and a list of options will appear. If you have Dropbox installed then it will be one of the options. 
[image: share list]