# Android app to record audio and upload to YouTube as video?

Tags: android, youtube, audio-recording, voice-recording

I am looking for an Android app that allows me to record voice audio and upload this audio as a video to a specified YouTube account. The app should run on Android 4.2.2. It can be paid or free.

Comment: Youtube app + Any basic video editor + any sound recorder = profit (?)

Comment: Basically yes but this in an all-in-one app to reduce complexity and ease the workflow.

Comment: That's a pretty specific scenario so I don't think there is an app built just for that. However you can use Tasker to automate at least a part of the process. Together with some Video/Audio editing and YouTube plugins you could probably even automate the whole thing. Another thing to consider is making an app to do this. You could also use an app that records voice and auto sends it to the cloud (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21071/android-voice-recorder-that-will-allow-me-to-save-to-dropbox?rq=1) and have a script on your computer process and upload the voice recording.

Comment: Thank you! Look what I found: [Spreaker allows to upload to YouTube](https://www.spreaker.com/help/podcasters).

Comment: Glad you found an answer to your question. You can answer yourself and select that as the accepted answer so this question gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Android app [Spreaker Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spreaker.android.studio) can record an audio voice file and upload this file as a video to a specified YouTube channel:

[image]

Source: https://www.spreaker.com/help/podcasters